# Kunena for Joomla uses nofollow for internal links

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

For some reason Kunena puts nofollow links for everything internal. This makes sense for all external links but certainly not for internal ones. I want Google to index the paths associated with the forum posts I have.

I'm hoping someone knows how to remove the nofollow links. It looks like this file is the main one: `components/com_kunena/lib/kunena.link.class.php`

There are a few functions where I remove the nofollow links such as:

```
static function GetHrefLink($link, $name, $title = '', $rel = 'nofollow', $class = '', $anker = '', $attr = '') {
            return '<a ' . ($class ? 'class="' . $class . '" ' : '') . 'href="' . $link . ($anker ? ('#' . $anker) : '') . '" title="' . $title . '"' . ($rel ? ' rel="' . $rel . '"' : '') . ($attr ? ' ' . $attr : '') . '>' . $name . '</a>';
    }

    //
    // Basic universal href link
    //
    static function GetSefHrefLink($link, $name, $title = '', $rel = 'nofollow', $class = '', $anker = '', $attr = '') {
            $uri = $link instanceof JURI ? $link : JURI::getInstance($link);
            if ($anker) $uri->setFragment($anker);
            return JHTML::_('kunenaforum.link', $uri, $name, $title, $class, $rel, $attr);
    }
```

I've tried removing the parameter everywhere, I tried just leaving it empty and I've tried using `follow` as a replacement. I've also tried looking for every single place where `nofollow` is shown in the whole Kunena component and tried removing those. Still no luck. Anyone with any ideas?

Kunena: 2.0.2
Joomla: 2.5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by changing this file: administrator/components/com_kunena/libraries/view.php

Find:

`public function getTopicLink`

Change this line:

```
return JHTML::_('kunenaforum.link', $uri, $content, $title, $class, 'nofollow');
```

to:

```
return JHTML::_('kunenaforum.link', $uri, $content, $title, $class, 'follow');
```

This exists in several spots.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to change nofollow because google will index whole topic and categories. Check url for topic if its indexed. And add RSS and sitemap to google webmaster. You can configure RSS@ kunena settings

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: No, Kunena doesn't follow a topic, just categories (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your original concern, you want to remove all the rel="nofollow" references.

I would do this with a free component called ReReplacer.  http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

Create a rereplacer item that searches for rel="nofollow" and replaces it with rel="follow".

I did this for a forum of Joomla users that we want them to have follow links in their signatures.

If you buy the pro version of rereplacer then you can specify the replacement for only Kunena.